# Downloading file from GitHub using Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, github

I'm trying to work with some data that appears in GitHub, but the code is wrong. This is the code,

```
url = r"https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/03-10-2020.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url,index_col=0,parse_dates=[0])
```

This is the pic of the output to that code:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Please post formatted text, not images.

Comment: This is missing the actual error

Comment: definitely look for the raw data. The link does not point to a raw csv file. it points to a webpage with csv content in it pus other stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/03-10-2020.csv"

print pd.read_csv(url,index_col=0,parse_dates=[0])
```

[image: Image of data]

Answer (score 1):

Your url goes to a github page (html) that shows the file contents, but is also a formatted pages with buttons and things.

Try this url: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/03-10-2020.csv`

Answer (score 1):

Just type 
`$git clone https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19.git`
Then 
`a='csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/03-10-2020.csv'
df=pd.read(a,index_col=0,parse_dates=[0])`

Answer (score 0):

If you download the file to the local folder you're working out of, and change the url to the local file name, then this will work.

Otherwise you're trying to access a complex html / javascript page that even using a browser tool, it might me tough to access the actual data in the csv file.